# How to programmatically set highlight animation for custom UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a very complicated logic that I have to trigger a event to UIButton with:

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.startButton.frame, point))
{
    [self buttonDidClicked:self.startButton];
}
```

It is not linked to any control event and it's unnecessary. The problem is that there is no highlight animation when the function is called. I am talking about the regular animation where there is a brief black mask applies to a UIButton when you click on it.

Then I tried to link the button to UIEventTouchDown control event and trigger the call by:

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.startButton.frame, point))
{
    [self.nextButton setHighlighted:YES];
    [self.backButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}
```

which simulates a real touch event. It does make a black layer on the button but it doesn't go off automatically.

What is the best way to do it? I want to get some feedback when the button is fired. The default animation is sufficient.

Comment: why dont you set [self.nextButton setHighlighted:NO]; after 0.5 sec delay?

Answer (score 1):

You can use layers or gradient layers in a way like this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];

        CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        loginButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
        UIColor *topColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255 green:255/255 blue:255/255 alpha:0.9];
        UIColor *middleColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:61.0/255 green:130.0/255 blue:244.0/255 alpha:1.0];
        UIColor *bottomColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:24.0/255 green:77.0/255 blue:214.0/255 alpha:1.0];
        gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)topColor.CGColor,
                           (id)middleColor.CGColor, (id)bottomColor.CGColor, nil];
        gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.05f],
                              [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7],
                              nil];
        gradient.frame = [[loginButton layer] bounds];
        gradient.cornerRadius = 4.0;
        gradient.borderWidth = 0.5;
        [loginButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [loginButton.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0]; 
        [loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loginTouchDown:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loginTouchUp:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
}

- (IBAction)loginTouchDown:(id)sender
{
        CAGradientLayer *gradient = [loginButton.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0];
        UIColor *topColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:24.0/255 green:77.0/255 blue:214.0/255 alpha:1.0];
        UIColor *middleColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:24.0/255 green:77.0/255 blue:214.0/255 alpha:1.0];
        UIColor *bottomColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:24.0/255 green:77.0/255 blue:214.0/255 alpha:1.0];
        gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)topColor.CGColor, (id)middleColor.CGColor,
                           (id)bottomColor.CGColor, nil];
}

- (IBAction)loginTouchUp:(id)sender
{
        CAGradientLayer *gradient = [loginButton.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0];
        UIColor *topColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255 green:255/255 blue:255/255 alpha:0.9];
        UIColor *middleColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:61.0/255 green:130.0/255 blue:244.0/255 alpha:1.0];
        UIColor *bottomColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:24.0/255 green:77.0/255 blue:214.0/255 alpha:1.0];
        gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)topColor.CGColor,
                           (id)middleColor.CGColor, (id)bottomColor.CGColor, nil];
}

- (IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender
{
        [self loginTouchUp:sender];
        [self doLogin];
}
```

Login button is defined in story board and assigned to local view property.

(in *.h file)

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *loginButton;
@end
```

(in *.m file)

```
@synthesize loginButton;
```

In viewdidload we define gradient layers for normal state and pushed state. Then we manipulate them on up/down event. We also need loginButton() as button handler to perform the action. This way this button behaviour is ideally the same as normal button. Seems this is it.

Example of how it works you can find in iphone app store. There is free app called Torchoo. When you run it, first thing it shows is login screen. It has login button. Press it see if this is what you need. This code is from that project.

Comment: this is not answer, its comment

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is to bind your `-buttonDidClicked` action to the UIButton UIControlEventTouchUpInside event:

```
[self.startButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonDidClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

If you need to use `CGRectContainsPoint()` mechanism you should set `self.startButton.highlighted` option to YES before `-buttonDidClicked` invocation and then to NO after it.

Comment: I can't bind because there is another view stealing all the events.

Comment: Ok, then try switching on and off .highlighted option.